# Percentage Calculation - SpotFire

Tags: spotfire

I am new to Spotfire.

I have a dataset as shown below. I need to count the percentage of "late" events year wise. For instance for the year 2016 "late" event percentage is (3/14)*100.

Could anyone please say the custom expression for this calculation in spotfire?

```
2018     OTC
2017     InProgress
2017     InProgress
2017     OTC
2016     Late
2016     OTC
2016     OTC
2016     OTC
2016     OTC
2016     Late
2016     Late
2016     OTC
2016     OTC
2016     InProgress
2016     InProgress
2016     OTC
2016     InProgress
2016     InProgress
2015     OTC
2015     OTC
2015     Late
2015     Late
2015     OTC
2015     OTC
```

Comment: Please give an example of what you have tried so far and what problems you are facing with those attempts, https://soundcloud.com/dr-meaker/sets/dirt-soul-album

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert a calculated column into your table, use this formula below. I made up the `[Status]` and `[Year]` columns since you didn't specify them in your data set.

```
Count(If(Trim([Status])="Late",[Status])) over ([Year]) / Count() over ([Year]) as [Percent Late for the Year]
```

If you are doing this in a cross table, then set your Horizontal Axis to `[Status]`, set your Vertical Axis to `[Year]` and then set the Cell Values to:

```
Count() THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.Rows]))
```

In both cases, I wouldn't multiple by 100 as you did in your question. Instead, change the formatting of the column to `PERCENTAGE`. You can accomplish this for the first solution (inserting the column) by going to Edit > Column Properties > Formatting and selecting Percentage. In a cross table Right Click > Properties > Formatting and select Percentage for the Axis Values.

Comment: Tried the first formula posted by "SCSIMON" and it works. Thanks. I tried the same formula earlier but without the last part " as [percent late for the year]". May i know what difference the last part" as [Percent Late for the year]" makes in the calculation? Is "[percent Late for the year]" a syntax? Please clarify

Comment: This is just what the column will be named. If you don't put as [Some Column] it will put the entire expression as your column name. You can change this to whatever you want the column named.

Comment: Forgot to add, it doesn't change the calculation at all.